# MS word: different caption style for figure and table

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, caption

I'm trying to add captions for figures and tables in MS word.

And I want to use different style on captions for figures and captions for tables. ex) font size 10 for captions for figures, font size 12 for captions for tables.

However, there is only one style for caption. How can I make it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I created CaptionT for tables (formatted as Keep with Next) and CaptionF for figures. It works well for large figures, where the NEXT style is Figure and Figure is formatted as keep with next, CaptionF is not. However, applying the Figure and Table caption style is a manual effort.

Some existing docs have simple numeric iteration Figure 1, Figure 2. If I insert ONE caption (T or F), and set it as Figure 1-1 (the first number is heading 1 identifier), all of the existing captions (T or F) automatically update to include the chapter identifier.

What I cannot seem to integrate into the Word UI is to USE CaptionF for a figure. There should be an option for setting this somewhere. Does anyone know where?

It is necessary for tables and figures in a Word Doc export of a database. If we don't use explicit caption ids, both the TOF and TOT have an intermingling of entries (even though they're formatted correctly in the database). So if the dual caption works for the DATABASE, I'd like to automate it within Word, for documents we create with Word. How do I do that?